# Origin of “haru-” in “haruspex”

Tags: etymology

I am trying to understand better the etymon of the first part of the word *haruspex*.

The [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/haruspex#Latin) and other sources mention «*haru-* (“intestines”)», but there seems to be no Latin word **haru* or the like (apart from derivate words such as *haruspex*, *hariolor* etc.). Wiktionary and [Lewis-Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=haruspex) mention older roots, from Faliscan, Sanskrit, Proto-Indoeuropean etc., while [Lewis's *Elementary Latin Dictionary*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aentry%3Dharuspex) tantalisingly records “HAR-”, but I can't find other references to this root as such in that book.

Are there more modern, more complete explanation of the *haru-* root?

Comment: One possible place to start is the [Wiktionary list of Latin words from the same PIE root](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Latin_terms_derived_from_the_PIE_root_*%C7%B5%CA%B0er-_(bowels)). Perhaps someone could check whether those words actually come from the same root according to reputable sources and write an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to de Vaan, Etymological Dictionary  of  Latin  and the other Italic  Languages:

> PIt.   *xaruspek-  'diviner',   *χαriο-.   It.  cognates:   Fal. 
>   harasp[ex]   ,   harisp[ex]   [nom.sg.]  'haruspex'.
>
> PIE *ǵʰrH-u- 
>   'intestines'. IE cognates: Skt. hirā 'vein', Lith. žarná 'intestine,
>   hose', Oic. gǫrn 'intestines* < *ǵʰorH-nh2-

Fal. is Faliscan.

According to Wiktionary the cognates are [zarna](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zarna) [gǫrn](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/g%C7%ABrn#Old_Norse)  [zorrë](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zorr%C3%AB#Albanian) [Garn](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Garn#German) [χορδή](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%87%CE%BF%CF%81%CE%B4%CE%AE#Ancient_Greek) all originating in [*ǵʰer-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/%C7%B5%CA%B0er-).

Other related Latin words according to Wiktionary are [hīra](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hira#Latin) "empty gut" and [hernia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hernia#Latin) "protruded viscus".

Comment: Re: *χαήο- Isn't there a typo in your quote? In my copy, I have *χαriο-

Comment: By the way: what is "hose" in this context?

Comment: @AlexB. Sorry for the OCR error, I fixed most of them, but this one remained.

Comment: @fdb Hose in this context is a rubber pipe, a garden hose, firefighter's hose - Schlauch, hadice,...